# listen EACCES: permission denied when port defined as variable

Tags: node.js, http

I have a simple NodeJS server. If I define the port to listen to as follows, it runs as expected:

```
server.listen(3000, () => {
    logger.info('listening on *:3000');
});
```

However, if I try to assign the port from a variable with the following code, I get an error.

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, () => {
    logger.info('listening on *:'+port);
}
```

Error:

> EACCES: permission denied

Any ideas what might be causing the EACCES error with the code above?

Comment: Have you checked the value of the port before passing it? Console it and try to add more code to the question. It should work though.

Comment: If you add console.log responses on the question then it must be easier for others to understand and share you the correct pointers

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured this out. It was due to me having bad character in my .env file.